# java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class after creation new module in gradle

Tags: spring, gradle, classnotfoundexception

I have added new module to project and pasted new sources there.

I have built application and then start.

I see the following error while starting:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect bean class [MyClass] for persistence metadata: could not find class that it depends on
.....
Caused by: 
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: MyClass
```

`MyClass` resides in new module.

build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compile project(':my-old-module')
}
```

Any ideas?